# Make Plot3D only the real values of a function

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot only the real values of a function of two variables $ z=f(x,y) $, i.e. $ z\in\mathbb{R} $. I am not interested in the region over which the image of the function is complex, i.e. $ z\in\mathbb{C} $.

The problem is that $ f $ is real only in a certain "hard-to-define" region of the $ (x,y) $ plane and imaginary in the remaining region. So it would be much simpler to tell `Plot3D` to only plot real values and ignore the complex ones. What happens with the default settings is that `Plot3D` plots the real part of $ f $ and ignore the complex one.

EDIT:
The function that I am trying to plot is quite complicated:
$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{3} \left(1-\frac{\cos (4 x)+\cos (4 y)-2}{ \sin ^2\left(2 \arcsin \left(\sqrt{\sin ^2(x)+\sin
   ^2(y)}\right)\right)}\right)$

```
f = 1/3 (1 - (-2 + Cos[4 x] + Cos[4 y])/Sin[2 ArcSin[Sqrt[Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2]]]^2)
```

Here the plot of the function "as is":

```
 Plot3D[f, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image]

Here the plot of the imaginary part of the function

```
 Plot3D[Im[f], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image]

As you can see the imaginary part is non-null inside the "squares". I would like to know how to make `Plot3D` ignore those regions when plotting. Thanks

Comment: This you get automatically. Just try this: `f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 - y^2]; Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`. In the domains where the function `f[x,y]` is complex `Plot3D` builds nothing at all.

Comment: I propose to close this question as an off-topic. The reason is that it is based on the lack of the basic knowledge of Mma functions described in the documentation.

Comment: Can you give us more information about the function?  As Alexei says, `Plot3D` generally only plots the real-valued portion of a function.  But... Something like `Plot3D[x + 10^-14 I y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` will plot a surface because "small" imaginary parts are quietly discarded since they can frequently arise as numerical errors during calculations.  Is this what you're running into?

Comment: I added further details to the answer. I would like to stress that I have already searched the documentation and on google for an answer but I couldn't anything specific to my case.

Comment: Can you provide the Wolfram Language code required for people to do this on their own...........

Comment: @Brett Champion Thanks for the suggestion. However, the imaginary part is even divergent in some segments of the plane so that is not the case I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)  or [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) to focus on part of the domain on which `f` is real:

```
Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[f, Im[f] == 0], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> {0, 3}]
```

[image]

```
f2[x_, y_] := Evaluate@f;  
Plot3D[f2[x, y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, RegionFunction -> (Im[f2[#, #2]] == 0 &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @LastStarDust, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

The real values correspond to the region where `Im[Sin[2 ArcSin[Sqrt[Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2]]]^2] == 0`. To define the function only in this region, use `Condition`, aka `/;`, like this

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_] := 
 1/3 (1 - (-2 + Cos[4 x] + Cos[4 y]) /
      Sin[2 ArcSin[Sqrt[Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2]]]^2) /; 
  Im[Sin[2 ArcSin[Sqrt[Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2]]]^2] == 0

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Comment: This answer is correct too.